# NullPointerException with Set<String> size() == 0

Tags: java

I initialized `Set<String> j;`. How come when I do this

```
  for loop {
      if (case1) {
        j.add(val);
        if (j.size() > 1) {
          return false;
        } else {
          continue;
        }
      }
   }
return true;
```

I get a `NullPointerException`? Shouldn't the loop continue because if nothing is added Set is size 0?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer will do

Comment: `Set<String> j;` is only a declaration, not initialization

Comment: @DnR youre totally right. My mistake!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually assign a set type to `j`. You've *declared* it, but haven't *initialized* it - very different.

Try `Set<String> j = new HashSet<String>();`.

Comment: I think this will solve my question thank you! testing now! I forgot all abotu hashset

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize j:

```
Set<String> j = new HashSet<String>();
```

Also, instead of what you're doing now, do this:

```
  for loop {
      if (case1) {
        j.add(val);
        if (!j.isEmpty()) {
          return false;
        } else {
          continue;
        }
      }
   }
```

Just for clarity.